# Overwrite access database from excel table using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access-2016, vba

I've searched this website for my question, but unable to locate solution.
I'm a beginner for excel VBA, Need some help help in updating old data in access database with new data from excel spreadsheet using excel-VBA.

From internet i've created the following steps.

Step1 : Uploading initial data (I've got a working VBA macro for this step):

Upload excel table:

[image: Upload excel table]

Step 2 : Downloading data from access to excel (I've working VBA macro for this step)

Download from access:

[image: Download from access]

Step 3 : Now, I want to overwrite entire access table with revised data from excel table. I'm unable to locate macro for this step.

Overwrite from excel to access:

[image: Overwrite from excel to access]

Please help me with a VBA program or any website link for this step.

I'm unable to attach the excel sheet here.

Comment: You should clear the table before uploading the new data

Answer (score 0):

Finally found macro from other source, sharing the code for any other beginner

```
Sub Modify()

Dim dbs As ADODB.Connection
Dim rset1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim FName As String
Dim i As Long, j As Integer

FName = "C:\Users\temp\Database - Copy.accdb" 'change as needed
Set dbs = New ADODB.Connection
 dbs.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
 "Data Source=" & FName
Set rset1 = New ADODB.Recordset: rset1.CursorLocation = adUseClient

Set ws = Worksheets("Import") 'update sheet name as needed.
lr = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 10 To lr
    rset1.Open "SELECT * FROM [DB] WHERE [ID] = " & ws.Range("B" & i).Value, dbs, , adLockOptimistic
    With rset1
        For j = 1 To rset1.Fields.Count - 1
            .Fields(j).Value = ws.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, j).Value
        Next j
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
Next i

Set rset1 = Nothing
dbs.Close: Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```